# Generate Entity classes in Spring by using Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, orm, spring-data

Is it possible to generate "entity" classes in Spring starting from an existent database by using Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible for example with Hibernate Tools, have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/).